# Racket contract and struct issue

Tags: struct, racket, contract

I am learning Racket for an Artificial Intelligence class. For the first project, the teacher gave us a file with contracts and unit tests, we are to code the functions required to make it run. I just created stubs of the functions I will need and met all the contracts except one:

```
[start-state (and/c state? (not/c state-game-over?))]
```

The function I declared looks like this at the moment:

```
(define (start-state)
  (state '() start-tiles 0)
)
```

And the state struct was given by the teacher:

```
(struct state (played unplayed passes) #:prefab)
```

With contract:

```
[struct state ((played (listof (and/c tile? tile-at-origin?)))
             (unplayed (listof (and/c tile? tile-on-board?)))
             (passes pass-count?))]
```

This crashes with error:

```
start-state: broke its contract
promised: (and/c state? (not/c state-game-over?))
produced: #<procedure:start-state>
which isn't: state?
in: (and/c state? (not/c state-game-over?))
contract from:
```

I believe my start-state procedure creates and returns a state struct, but apparently it returns itself and violates the contract. How do I return the struct and not the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `start-state` isn't supposed to be a procedure, but a value. That is, you need to do

```
(define start-state (start ...))
```

instead of

```
(define (start-state) ...)
```

Comment: That solved it. Thank you! How do you know the difference between a procedure and a value in the contract? I am not used to it yet, to me, all the contracts provided look the same so I assumed everything was procedures.

Comment: Usually a contract for a function will use `->`. For example `(-> integer? boolean?)` is a function that expects an `integer?` and returns a `boolean?`. You can also use a dot notation reader trick to write it infix, like this: `(integer? . -> . boolean?)`.  Of course, you might have a named contract that is an alias or wrapper for a `->` contract, but at bottom it will be `->` (or a few variations of arrows like `->*`).

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, @GregHendershott!  I knew how to fix the problem of "procedure vs. (non-procedure) value", but I haven't used Racket's contracts before.

Comment: Wow that makes contracts so much easier to understand! Thank you for your help @GregHendershott